# Stopping .each execution on every iteration for a spesific time interval in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, each, intervals

I am trying to create the following functionality in my javascript:

```
$("mySelector").each(function(){

// Do something (e.g. change div class attribute)   
// call to MyFunction(), the iteration will stop here as long as it will take for myFunction to complete

});

function myFunction() 
{   
 // Do something for e.g. 5 seconds 
}
```

My question is how can I stop every iteration for the duration of the myFunction()?

Comment: As long as myFunction is synchronous, that should'nt really be a problem as there is only one thread, and javascript is normally synchronous, so it will wait for the class to change before the next loop starts anyway.

Comment: While you're waiting, the browser is frozen. Synchronous, long-running processes in JavaScript aren't a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var step = 0;
    var content = $("mySelector");
    var max = content.length;
    var speed = 5000; // ms


    var handle = setInterval(function () {
        step++;
        if (step >= max) {
            clearInterval(handle);
        } else {
            var item = content[step];
            // do something
        }
    }, speed);
}());
```

`setInterval` will do it once-every-n-miliseconds, and `clearInterval` will stop it when you're done.  This won't lock up the browser (provided your "do something" also doesn't).  **FRAGILE:** it assumes that the results of `$("mySelector")` are valid for the duration of the task.  If that isn't the case then inside `do something` then validate `item` again.

Answer (score 3):

No, that isnt possible. You'll have to code it differently, possibly with a setTimeout based on the current index of .each.

```
$("mySelector").each(function(i){

    // Do something (e.g. change div class attribute)   
    // call to MyFunction(), the iteration will stop here as long as it will take for myFunction to complete
    setTimeout(myFunction,i*5000);

});

function myFunction() 
{   
 // Do something for e.g. 5 seconds 
}
```

Edit: You can also do it with queuing: http://jsfiddle.net/9Bm9p/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $(".test");
    var queue = $("<div />");

    divs.each(function(){
        var _this = this;
        queue.queue(function(next) {
            myFunction.call(_this,next); 
        });
    });
});

function myFunction(next) {    
    // do stuff
    $(this).doSomething(); 

    // simulate asynchronous event
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(self.id);
        // go to next item in the queue
        next();
    },2000);

}
```

​

Comment: But `setTimeout` doesn't really hold the call.. his `.each` is just going to continue with next iteration

Comment: @Vega right, but the function itself will be called in the correct sequence, every 5 seconds until they are all iterated through.

Comment: @Vega see `i*5000` the first one will be called instantly, the second one after 5 seconds, the 3rd one after 10 seconds, etc.

Comment: @KevinB smart move on `i*5000` missed that one totally. Yup, noticed that.. Oh wait, but that doesn't include the code that is getting executed inside his `.each` ;)

Comment: This is assuming the code inside of myFunction will run 5 seconds exactly. The OP uses "e.g. 5 seconds" as an example. Maybe each run of myFunction produces a different amount of time of execution, therefore you can't just hardcode 5 seconds in.

Comment: @ianpgall The only way around that would be to not use either of them (setTimeout/setInterval) and to instead use a queuing system that will run myfunction, but myfunction will have to indicate back to the queuing system that it is done running at each step.

Comment: @KevinB Not exactly, look at the answer I just posted. It involves callbacks, technically, but it still uses setTimeout without a queuing system.

Comment: @ianpgall True, but that's really all a queue does.

Comment: @KevinB True, but it's not some queuing system that needs managed. It's a "queuing" or callback system that allows for normal execution and doesn't hardcode anything in.

Comment: For example, what if myFunction makes an AJAX call to the server to retrieve something, and then put the result into a div (for each item selected). There's no way to tell how long it'll take to get to the server, how long the server will take to process it, and how long it'll take the server to return the results. I guess hardcoding 5000 milliseconds is safe enough then.........

Comment: @KevinB I mean, that looks good too. I guess it depends on preference, unless you can think of a reason to use it over mine, or a reason to use mine over that. Either way, it's using a callback system in my opinion. Or I'm sure a combination of both of ours could be made or whatever. There's many possibilities

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsFiddle that I think will do what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Bm9p/2/

You would just need to replace the selector with what you use.

The "loop" that is occurring will wait for `myFunction` to finish before moving on to the next element. I added the setTimeout inside of `myFunction` to simulate it taking a period of time. If you are using asynchronous things, such as an AJAX request, you would need to put the call to `myFunction` inside of the `complete` method...or in the callback of an animation.

But as someone already commented, if everything in `myFunction` is synchronous, you should be able to use it as you are. If you are looking for this process to be asynchronous, or if things in `myFunction` are asynchronous, you cannot use a for loop or .each().